# Python create a dictionary using __new__ and add an attribute for each key

Tags: python

I am building a python class in which I create a dictionnary using the method "**new**". Then, I would like to define a method to affect a unit for some of the keys. Below an example of the code:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    dict = {key1:None, key2:None}
    return dict

  def unit(self, unit):
    self[KEY].unit = unit
```

Where, in the unit method, KEY should take any key of the dictionnary. Could you please help me to understand how to code it?

In advance thank you,

Comment: Most probably you want to have an __init__ function.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do not use the `__new__` method. It's almost always a mistake and is definitely so in your example. You should be subclassing `dict`. It is also not clear where or how the magic `KEY` var is defined. I recommend you rephrase your question in terms of your goals rather than in terms of getting your example to work using the `__new__()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, why you want to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`, but you can simply iterate through all keys in the dictionary by doing:

```
class dictionary_setter:
  some_dic = {'key1':1, 'some_other_key':2, 'just another key':3}

def __init__(self,keys):
  self.some_dic = {}
  for k in keys:
    self.some_dic[k]='some_value'

a_test_dic = dictionary_setter(['key1','key2'])
print(a_test_dic.some_dick['key1'])
```

Turning a string into a variable is another topic, but you can simply refer to the dictionary entry via dot syntax.

Comment: I can not return a dictionary with __init__.

And I would like to do something like:

`
from MyClass import *
dict = MyClass()
dict["key1"].unit = "m/s"
`

Comment: You don't have to. You can simply refer to the dictionary. Are you coming from C/Java over to python?

Comment: From fortran to python

Comment: I updated the example to show, how you can append a dictionary to the instance of a class.

Comment: I agree with that, but I still cannot affect an attirbute UNIT to "some_dic" using only the key. Cf. def unit(self, unit): self.some_dic[key].unit = unit